# Dynamic JSON matrix values exclude

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to skip `build-dot` job for specific values coming from matrix JSON.

Matrix JSON example:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "Api",
        "project": "dotnet",
    },
   {
        "name": "SideApi",
        "project": "nodejs",
    },
]
```

Workflow:

```yaml
    jobs:
    
      get-matrix:
        name: Get Matrix
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        outputs:
          matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
        steps:
    
        - name: Git checkout
          uses: actions/checkout@v4
    
        - name: Set Matrix
          id: set-matrix
          run: |
            JSON=$(cat ./module-matrix.json | tr -d " \t\n\r")
            echo "$JSON"
            echo "matrix=${JSON//'%'/'%25'}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    
    
      build-dot:
        name: DotNet build
        needs: [get-matrix]
        uses: ./.github/workflows/_build-dotnet.yml
        strategy:
          fail-fast: false
          matrix: 
            include: ${{ fromJson(needs.get-matrix.outputs.matrix) }}
            exclude:
              - project: nodejs
        secrets: inherit
        with:
          module: ${{ matrix.name }}
          version: ${{ needs.create-version.outputs.version }}
```

Just using `exclude` does not work, pipeline still running. How to exclude values with the dynamic JSON matrix? I want to skip all that `project` = `nodejs`.

Comment: [_"**Note:** All `include` combinations are processed after `exclude`. This allows you to use `include` to add back combinations that were previously excluded."_](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategymatrixexclude)